# OpenTelemetry Python: gevent monkey patch errors when using auto instrumentation

Tags: open-telemetry

I am trying auto instrumentation for python, referring to https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/getting-started/ Everything works fine.

However, after I added the `gevent monkey patch` at the beginning, like this.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from random import randint
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/rolldice")
def roll_dice():
    return str(do_roll())

def do_roll():
    return randint(1, 6)
```

Then the errors comes out when running `opentelemetry-instrument` command.

```
(my-3.9) gaolvyang:ot-python$ opentelemetry-instrument --traces_exporter console --metrics_exporter console flask run
/home/gaolvyang/project/ot-python/app.py:2: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util (/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py)', 'urllib3.util.ssl_ (/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)'].
  monkey.patch_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/my-3.9/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1047, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 911, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 897, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 312, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "/home/gaolvyang/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/my-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 161, in __exit__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 116, in release
RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock
```

If I run `flask run` without using `opentelemetry-instrument`, it works fine.

Seems cannot use `opentelemetry-instrument` and `gevent monkey patch` at the same time.

Would anybody help with this? Thanks!